# how to set primary key in parse?

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, primary-key

I'm using "Parse" to save the data when the user stops playing the game, I have been integrating on Facebook, data like number of bombs , number of hammers etc. I am using the JavaScript developers guide for that. So far I have managed to save the data using the following code :

```
                  var PlayerData = Parse.Object.extend("PlayerData");
                      var playerData = new PlayerData();
                      playerData.save({
                        gola:0,
                        bull:0,
                        ham:0,
                        bru:0,
                        eye:0,
                        playerName: "null"

                      }, {
                        success: function(playerData) {
                          // The object was saved successfully.
                          alert("saved");
                          console.log("objectid",playerData.id);

                        },
                        error: function(playerData, error) {
                          // The save failed.
                          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                          alert(error.message);
                        }
                      });
```

and then update the data using

```
                       playerData.save(null, {
                          success: function(playerData) {
                            playerData.set("gola", gPlayerBombs);
                            playerData.set("bru", gPaintBrush);
                            playerData.set("ham", gPlayerHammer);
                            playerData.set("eye", gColorPicker);
                            playerData.set("bull", gPlayerBulldozers);
                            playerData.set("playerName", bandaName);
                            playerData.save();
                          }
                        });
```

but the problem with this is that it creates multiple record in the table each time I start and play the game .Instead I want to update and fetch the same row/record for each unique player any suggestion? . For that I need to set the primary key . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For updating an object, you need to keep a reference of the object you want to update. Let me roughly psuedo code it for you.

```
var pQ = Parse.Query("YOUR PLAYER CLASS");
pQ.get("ID OF THE PARTICULAR OBJECT YOU WANT TO UPDATE", {
    success: function(object) {
        //UPDATE YOUR object HERE
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
        //ERROR
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.